# How to react to to user scrolling on Accompanist Pager?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-accompanist

The Accompanist Pager [documentation](https://google.github.io/accompanist/pager/#reacting-to-page-changes) suggests reacting to page changes as follows :

```
val pagerState = rememberPagerState()

LaunchedEffect(pagerState) {
    // Collect from the pager state a snapshotFlow reading the currentPage
    snapshotFlow { pagerState.currentPage }.collect { page ->
        AnalyticsService.sendPageSelectedEvent(page)
    }
}

VerticalPager(
    count = 10,
    state = pagerState,
) { page ->
    Text(text = "Page: $page")
}
```

How can we distinguish scrolling to a page from user gesture, and scrolling to a page using `animateScrollingToPage()` / `scrollingToPage()` ? I would like to perform a certain action only on user scroll, not on programmatic scroll.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to the problem?

Comment: @testivanivan Not yet

Answer (score 0):

Did you try :

```
val isScrollInProgressFlow = snapshotFlow { pagerState.isScrollInProgress }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I solved it using [interactionsSource](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/interaction/InteractionSource). No interaction is emitted when automatic scroll happens. But it emits interactions on user actions.

You can also use other interaction source types.

```
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    pagerState.interactionSource.interactions
        .collect {
            if (it is DragInteraction.Start) {
                Log.d("test", "User interaction is started")
            }
        }
}
```

In my case I had to cancel automatic scroll on user drag. The simplified version looks like this:

```
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {

    val autoscrollJob = launch {
        while(true) {
            yield() // exit the coroutine if the job is completed
            delay(autoScrollDelay)
            animateScrollToPage(
                page = (currentPage + 1) % pageCount
            )
        }
    }

    launch {
        interactionSource.interactions
            .collect {
                if (it is DragInteraction.Start) {
                    autoscrollJob.cancel()
                }
            }
    }
}
```